# Is it possible to assign a value to already declared variable in NuoDB

Tags: sql, nuodb

Is it possible to assign a value to a variable in NuoDB **after the variable is created.**

I've tried:

```
VAR $test string;
$test = 'test';
```

But it says:

```
[Code: -1, SQL State: 42000]  syntax error on line 1
$test = 'test'
^ expected statement got $test
```

According to their examples "[Example 2: Redefining variables within a stored procedure](http://doc.nuodb.com/Latest/Content/SQL-Procedural-Variables.htm)"

> "A variable cannot be redefined, using the same name, within the same
>   scope or code block."

Wasn't able to find anything else regarding the variables in the docs. But something might have slipped out from me..
And moreover, it's incredible to have a variable without an opportunity to change it's value! Sounds like a nonsense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, I suspect that you simply need to change the DELIMITER.

Try:

```
SQL> set delimiter @
    Delimiter is now [@]
SQL> var $test string;
   > $test = 'abc';
   > select $test from dual@

 $TEST  
 ------ 

  abc   

SQL>
```

Cheers!

Nik

Comment: Thanks mate. 
But still didn't work with similar error:

set DELIMITER @;
VAR $test string;
$test = 'test';


VAR $test string;
^ expected end of statement got VAR

Comment: Hi Sergey, - I'm not sure I understand the output you've pasted.

Your pasted output shows 3 statements:
1. define var $test;
2. assign value into $test;
3. redefine var $test;

As far as I can see, if you redefine a variable in the same scope you will get an error message.

Just checking, was that 3rd statement actually there, or is that an error in pasting the output into your comment?

Comment: I should also clarify:

Are you doing this in a Stored Procedure, or as a SQL script - for example directly at the nuosql command-line?

Comment: I've edited my example to show actually using the variable, and that it "works".

Comment: One additional clarification:

In NuoDB you can declare a variable separately from assigning its value, or you can declare a variable *and* assign its value in a single statement.

The code in the Example you linked to does the latter, so the 2 statements which are assigning values to l_local_var are *both* declaring *and* assigning the variable.

The cause of the error message is that there are 2 declarations of the variable, *not* that there are 2 assignments.

Comment: Hi Nik,
the 3rd line was to show the error thrown with the statement caused it. So last "VAR $test string;" is a reference thrown by Nuo upon the error. 
I'm using DB Visualizer GUI tool to access the Nuo. Working with a simple script but not procedures/functions/triggers.

Comment: And eventually, I've found where was the issue. It was so silly of me... It was just because of the way I've been launching script. There were 3 buttons, to execute a query in a certain way, but the one I've used was just to execute a line under current position of a cursor.. Seems it has been trying to launch a separate line but not all the query. I've just tried a shortcut and it had gone well.

Comment: Again thanks for your time sir! If I had had a reputation > 15 I would have increased your :)  As a matter of fact, it was no problem with the code, but just with crooked hands =)

Answer (score 0):

eventually found that the problem was in the way I've been launching the script.

It was so silly of me... It was just because of the way I've been launching script. There were 3 buttons, to execute a query in a certain way, but the one I've used was just to execute a line under current position of a cursor.. Seems it has been trying to launch a separate line but not all the query. I've just tried a shortcut and it had gone well.

Thus, as a matter of fact, it was no problem with the code, but just with crooked hands =)